# How can I retrieve the id of a document I added to a Cosmosdb collection?

Tags: azure, entity, azure-cosmosdb, primary-key, primary-key-design

I have a single collection into which I am inserting documents of different types. I use the type parameter to distinguish between different datatypes in the collection. When I am inserting a document, I have created an Id field for every document, but Cosmosdb has a built-in id field.

How can I insert a new document and retrieve the id of the created Document all in one query?

Comment: Not sure what you're want.If you don't set an id field , cosmos db will generate it automaticlly for you. Do you mean you want to retrieve document by this auto-generate id field?

Comment: Yes. I want to let cosmosdb generate the id for me, but I want to read it immediately and use it to perform further operations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you just need to `.getResource()` method to get the create document obj.

Please refer to the ***java code***:

```
DocumentClient documentClient = new DocumentClient(END_POINT,
                    MASTER_KEY, ConnectionPolicy.GetDefault(),
                    ConsistencyLevel.Session);

Document document = new Document();
document.set("name","aaa");

document = documentClient.createDocument("dbs/db/colls/coll",document,null,false).getResource();

System.out.println(document.toString());

//then do your business logic with the document.....
```

***C# code:***

```
Parent p = new Parent
            {
                FamilyName = "Andersen.1",
                FirstName = "Andersen",
            };

Document doc = client.CreateDocumentAsync("dbs/db/colls/coll",p,null).Result.Resource;
Console.WriteLine(doc);
```

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 5):

The **`CreateDocumentAsync`** method returns the created document so you should be able to get the document id.

```
 Document created = await client.CreateDocumentAsync(collectionLink, order);
```

Comment: CreateDocumentAsync returns a Task<ResourceResponse<Document>> not a Task<Document>, so I don't think this will work.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you could always fetch the `id` from creation method response in your favorite API as already shown in other answers. You may have reasons why you want to delegate key-assigning to DocumentDB, but to be frank, I don't see any good ones.

If inserted document would have no `id` set DocumentDB would generate a GUID for you. There wouldn't be any notable difference compared to **simply generating a new GUID yourself and assign it into id-field before save**. Self-assigning the identity would let you simplify your code a bit and also let you use the identity not only after persisting but also BEFORE. Which could simplify a lot of scenarios you may have or run into in future.

Also, note that you don't have to use GUIDs as as `id` and could use any unique value you already have. Since you mentioned  you have and `Id` field (which by name, I assume to be a primary key) then you should consider reusing this instead introducing another set of keys.

Self-assigned non-Guid key is usually a better choice since it can be designed to match your data and application needs better than a GUID. For example, in addition to being just unique, it may also be a natural key, narrower, human-readable, ordered, etc.

Comment: Personally I don't believe that any natural keys *that meet the uniqueness and stability requirements of a key* exist in the real world.